Crewai is not generating complete output
I am using Crewai with Claude api. I am trying to get an analysis report on logs. When I increase the number of logs, output generation is stoping mid way.
security_log_task = Task(
description=(
"Evaluate the provided {log1} to determine if they are security-related. "
"Focus on identifying whether each entry poses a security threat or is benign. "
"Remove all non-security threats. Process logs in batches if necessary to handle large           datasets."
),
expected_output=(
"A report with only security logs, saved to a file in JSON format. "
"Ensure all processed logs are included in the output, using pagination or multiple files if needed."
),
tools=[],
agent=security_analyst,
output_file=os.path.join(output_dir, "security_log_analysis.json")
)


When I increase the log size from 20 logs to 50 logs. The output json is not generated completely.
